# Pig UDF not finding WritableComparable

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-pig

I am getting the following error when trying to compile my Pig UDF with maven (or with my IDE IntelliJ for that matter) :

```
cannot access org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable
class file for org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable not found
```

So I figured I'd add a dependency to hadoop-core to my POM file but still no change, though I checked and the WritableComparable class is in the jar.

My UDF class looks like this :

```
public class INCREMENTAL_UPDATE extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {

    TupleFactory tupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
    BagFactory bagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();


    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (null == input || input.size() != 0) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            DataBag inputbag = (DataBag) input.get(0);
            Iterator it = inputbag.iterator();

            DataBag outputbag = bagFactory.newDefaultBag();

            Tuple previousTuple = null;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Tuple currentTuple = (Tuple) it.next();
                Tuple outputTuple = tupleFactory.newTuple();

                for (int i = 0; i < currentTuple.size(); i++) {
                    Object currentvalue = currentTuple.get(i);
                    if (currentvalue == null) {
                        outputTuple.append(currentvalue);
                    } else {
                        outputTuple.append(previousTuple.get(i));
                    }
                }

                previousTuple = outputTuple;
                outputbag.add(outputTuple);
           }
            return outputbag;
        } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new IOException("UDF INCREMENTAL_UPDATE failed");
        }
    }
}
```

I am yet to figure out if this would actually work, since I'm unsure if a UDF is distributed. If it is, that previousTuple probably would not work. But I can't even test that out because I can't compile because of the error above.

Comment: I haven't used maven to compile a UDF jar, I only use ant, so I can't help with that.  But your `previousTuple` trick won't work. The `exec` function is run on each record, so `previousTuple` will always be `null`. However, you could make `previousTuple` a class member and it would probably carry over its state to the next record.  Since records could be processed in an unpredictable order, though, it's not clear if this would be useful.

Answer (score 7):

I was also receiving this error and was finally able to compile by including the Hadoop class path along with the pig.jar file.

```
javac -cp pig-0.11.0.jar:\`hadoop classpath\`  UPPER.java
```

If this doesn't work, try it without the slashes :

```
javac -cp pig-0.11.0.jar:`hadoop classpath`  UPPER.java
```

Answer (score 3):

Including `hadoop-common-2.3.0.jar` should resolved the exception.